# Using parameter markers with DB2 for z/OS's encryption syntax in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, encryption, db2

Trying to use a Prepared Statement so I don't have to deal with messy conversions or worry about injection, but it doesn't seem to be possible when encrypting columns in DB2 for z/OS on an insert.

Here is a sample of what kind of error I get when attempting an insert:

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into CONTENTSOURCE (CONTENTSOURCE_ID, CS_NAME) values (?, ENCRYPT(?))]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.12.55

Edit*: So, putting `ENCRYPT(CAST(? as VARCHAR(1048) FOR BIT DATA))` in appears to work. But I'm running into a problem with batch updates. The same query that works for a single insert gives

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.io: Error for batch element #1: VARIABLE  IS NOT DEFINED OR NOT USABLE

as an error when attempting the batchExecute

Comment: Try providing the data type information for the parameter: `...VALUES ( ?, ENCRYPT ( CAST (? AS <whatever data type your parameter is>) ) )`

Comment: This is the next step I've been testing out, and so far it looks like it works. Seems like weird behavior that you have to be so specific, instead of getting to put in a byte array and being rejected on the DB end if the input is too long.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. There may be several implementations of `ENCRYPT()` on the server, which accept parameters of different data types. DB2 has to know which implementation to choose when it compiles (prepares) the statement, and the untyped parameter marker does not provide enough information, obviously.

Comment: From my understanding of the feature through documentation, `ENCRYPT()` can only be performed on `VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA`, which takes a byte array in JDBC. Now, knowing IBM doc, it's possible the redbook that I'm using as reference doesn't show the whole picture and this is why I'm a little confused, but why should the requirements for using a parameter marker in `ENCRYPT()` be any different than those for `VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA`?